# 2d array element modification randomly

Tags: c++

I have 2d array (10x12), and they have 0 and 1s in them. I want to count the 1s in each array and I have two cases here: (1) if an array has more than three 1s, say k many, then generate k - 3 random variables and replace that many 1s with 0s if that random variable corresponds to a 1. (2)if an array has less than three 1s, say q many, then generate 3 - q random variables and replace that many 0s with 1s if that random variable corresponds to a 0. I have the following code so far. I need some suggestions here, I could not construct the code well.

```
int y[10];
int r[10];

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{          
    for(int j=0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        y[i] += Array[i][j]; 
    }

    if(y[i] > 3)
    {
        f = y[i] - 3;
        if(Array[i][r[f]] ==1)
            Array[i][r[f]] = 0;
    }

    if(y[i] < 3)
    {
        f = 3 - y[i];
        if(Array[i][r[f]] ==0)
            Array[i][r[f]] = 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#define ROW                (10)
#define COL                (12)
#define NUM_ONES_THRESHOLD (3)

int numOnes = 0, elementsToModify, randRow, randCol;
bool toggleUp;

/* Count 1s */
for(int row = 0; row < ROW; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < COL; col++)
        numOnes += Array[row][col];   
}

/* Determine How Many Elements To Modify */
if(numOnes > NUM_ONES_THRESHOLD)
{
    elementsToModify = numOnes - NUM_ONES_THRESHOLD;
    toggleUp = false;
}
else
{
    elementsToModify = NUM_ONES_THRESHOLD - numOnes;
    toggleUp = true;
}

/* Modify Table */
while(elementsToModify > 0)
{
    randRow = rand() % ROW;
    randCol = rand() % COL;

    if((Array[randRow][randCol] == 1) && !toggleUp)
    {
        Array[randRow][randCol] = 0;
        elementsToModify --;
    }

    if((Array[randRow][randCol] == 0) && toggleUp)
    {
        Array[randRow][randCol] = 1;
        elementsToModify --;
    }
}
```

It can be optimized.  I'll leave that as an exercise for you...